# Como criar um controller com os dados de outra tabela no ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, controller

Não estou sabendo criar adequadamente um Controller de Funcionário. A classe Funcionario está ligada a três outras, sendo CBO, Empresa e Departamento.

Logo, o no esquema do Banco de Dados, elas recebem estas três chaves primárias.
Meu grande problema então é que não estou sabendo criar o Controller para Criar, Editar, Detalhar e Excluir, apenas o Index que consegui fazer.

Bem como, estou com problemas na criação das Views, onde a View do Create funciona, mas depois que clico em salvar, volta pro Index de Funcionario e não persiste, não salvando.
Não sei mais o que fazer!

Aqui encontra-se o Controller:

```
public class FuncionarioController : Controller
{
    // GET: Unidade
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(FuncionarioDAO.BuscarTodos());
    }

    // GET: Unidade/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Funcionario i = FuncionarioDAO.BuscarPorId(id);
        if (i == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(i);
    }

    // GET: Unidade/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.empresas = EmpresaDAO.BuscarTodos();
        ViewBag.departamentos = DepartamentoDAO.BuscarTodos();
        ViewBag.cbos = CboDAO.BuscarTodos();

        return View();

    }

    // POST: Unidade/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            Funcionario t = new Funcionario();
            t.Nome = Convert.ToString(collection["Nome"]);
            t.Matricula = Convert.ToString(collection["Matricula"]);
            t.Ctps = Convert.ToString(collection["Ctps"]);
            t.Endereco = Convert.ToString(collection["Endereco"]);
            t.Empresa = EmpresaDAO.BuscarPorId(Convert.ToInt32(collection["Empresa.Id"]));
            t.Departamento = DepartamentoDAO.BuscarPorId(Convert.ToInt64(collection["Departamento.Id"]));
            t.Cbo = CboDAO.BuscarPorId(Convert.ToInt64(collection["Cbo.Id"]));

            if (!FuncionarioDAO.Persistir(t))
            {
                return View();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // GET: Unidade/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Funcionario i = FuncionarioDAO.BuscarPorId(id);
        if (i == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(i);
    }

    // POST: Unidade/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            Funcionario i = new Funcionario();

            i.Id = id;
            i.Nome = collection["Nome"];
            i.Matricula = collection["Matricula"];
            i.Ctps = collection["Ctps"];
            i.Endereco = collection["Endereco"];
            i.Empresa = EmpresaDAO.BuscarPorId(Convert.ToInt32(collection["Empresa.Id"]));
            i.Departamento = DepartamentoDAO.BuscarPorId(Convert.ToInt64(collection["Departamento.Id"]));
            i.Cbo = CboDAO.BuscarPorId(Convert.ToInt64(collection["Cbo.Id"]));



            if (!FuncionarioDAO.Persistir(i))
                return View();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // GET: Unidade/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Funcionario i = FuncionarioDAO.BuscarPorId(id);
        if (i == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(i);
    }

    // POST: Unidade/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            FuncionarioDAO.Excluir(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, etc.. pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona a **comunidade**, caso necessite de ajuda, acesse a [help]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 0):

Olha recomendo você criar suas actions recebendo objetos ou invés de usar formcollection.

Da uma lida em: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Creio que com isso vai te ajudar.

Sobre seu erro de não persistir, debuga e ver se seu método !FuncionarioDAO.Persistir(t) está salvando? Pois o problema deve está nele, algum tipo de dado não tá batendo!

Comment: Olá, Ivan. Compreendi mais ou menos. Esse Collection é um padrão que meu professor solicitou que utilizasse, infelizmente não compreendo muito ainda da linguagem e por isso utilizei. Hehe

Sobre o método !FuncionarioDAO.Persistir(t), não está salvando não.
Embora eu tenha feito o teste no UnitTeste e persistiu normal. 
Eu mexi, tirei o IF com o ! e fiz de forma comum, ainda sim persistira o erro.

Eu não sei mais o que fazer, e agora ainda estou na dúvida se minha sintaxe na parte do Try está correta... :\

Comment: Com certeza o erro deve deve ta na sua DAO

Comment: Tipo, os DAOS, eu revisei, depois eu fiz os testes pelo Unit e eles persistem normalmente os dados, busca todos, busca por ID e atualiza.
Me disseram que alguns dados não estão declarados corretamente no Controller, mas não to sabendo como arrumar isso. :\

Comment: Nos campos departamento, cbo e empresa, passa apenas o ID..